# Bound Mismatch error java generics

Tags: java, generics, mismatch

Getting the error

Bound mismatch: The generic method insertData(TreeNode, E) of type BinarySearchTree is not applicable for 
 the arguments (TreeNode, T). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >

What is wrong with the below code?

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<? extends T>>
                                                          implements Tree<T> {

private TreeNode<T> root;

@Override
public void insert(T data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    root = insertData(root,data);
}

@Override
public void insert(TreeNode<T> node) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public T remove(T data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNode(T data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

private <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
        TreeNode<E> insertData(TreeNode<E> node, E data)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        node = new TreeNode<E>(data);
        //return node;
    }
    else if(node.data.compareTo(data) <= 0)
        node.left = insertData(node.left,data);
    else
        node.right = insertData(node.right,data);


    return node;
}

}
```

---

```
public class TreeNode<T> {

    public TreeNode<T> left;
    public TreeNode<T> right;
    public T data;

    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this

```
class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<? extends T>> implements Tree<T>
```

should be

```
class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Tree<T>
```

and `insertData` should probably use type `T` as well or change

```
<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
```

to

```
<E extends Comparable<E>>
```